# Why do I get "New session rejected" from PHP Debug using Atom

Tags: php, xdebug, atom-editor

Can anyone shed light on why I get "New session rejected" from PHP Debug using Atom?

I have installed xdebug and Apache recognises that it is installed, I am using an extension to enable debug from Firefox but inside Atom I get the error, and sometimes I don't get the error but the debugger still does not break. I have eliminated the Windows firewall as an issue but now I am stuck.

Here is the setting from my php.ini:

```
;xdebug
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0rc1-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey=atom-xdebug
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_log = C:\xampp\php\logs\xdebug.log
```

Here is the settings from config.cson:

```
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
  editor:
    fontSize: 16
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "8729c4aa-3989-14fa-78e9-968504643693"
  "php-debug":
    currentPanelMode: "bottom"
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
"php-debug":
  PathMaps: [
    "remotepath;localpath"
    "localhost:8080/rdportal/index.php;C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\rdportal"
  ]
  ServerPort: 9000
```

This is the error log I get:

```
Log opened at 2016-12-01 03:43:41
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9001.
W: Creating socket for 'localhost:9001', WSAPoll: 10022.
W: Creating socket for 'localhost:9001', WSAPoll: 10022.
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2016-12-01 03:43:41
```

---

Based on the error log, I discovered that xdebug 2.5 RC was flawed, and so I have now downgraded to version 2.4.1 of the .dll file and now instead of "new session rejected" I obtain "session initiated" - I have reset the port back to 9000 as per the default but still no break point. Instead the error log now contains:

```
Log opened at 2016-12-01 04:11:32
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/rdportal/index.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.6.1-dev" protocol_version="1.0" appid="6764" idekey="atom-xdebug"><engine version="2.4.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2016 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n "show_hidden" -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n "max_depth" -v 4
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -n "max_data" -v 1024
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 4 -n "max_children" -v 32
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 5 -n "multiple_sessions" -v 0
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="multiple_sessions" success="1"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 6 -t "line" -f "file://localhost:8080/rdportal/index.php/index.php" -n 134
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="6" id="67640073"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t "exception" -x "Fatal error"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="67640074"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 8 -t "exception" -x "Catchable fatal error"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="8" id="67640075"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 9 -t "exception" -x "Warning"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="9" id="67640076"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 10 -t "exception" -x "Strict standards"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="10" id="67640077"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 11 -t "exception" -x "Xdebug"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="11" id="67640078"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 12 -t "exception" -x "Unknown error"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="12" id="67640079"></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 13 -t "exception" -x "Notice"
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="13" id="67640080"></response>

<- run -i 14
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="14" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- stop -i 15
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stop" transaction_id="15" status="stopped" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2016-12-01 04:11:32
```

This is now the current config.cson:

```
"*":
  core:
    telemetryConsent: "limited"
  editor:
    fontSize: 16
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "8729c4aa-3989-14fa-78e9-968504643693"
  "php-debug":
    PathMaps: [
      "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\rdportal;localhost:8080/rdportal/index.php"
    ]
    PhpException:
      CatchableFatalError: false
      Deprecated: false
      FatalError: false
      Notice: false
      ParseError: false
      StrictStandards: false
      UnknownError: false
      Warning: false
      Xdebug: false
    currentPanelMode: "bottom"
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
```

and this is the xdebug section of php.ini:

```
;xdebug
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I have found the problem to be my Path Maps - they were the wrong way round. So in summary, the 2.5 download is not reliable and the Path Map remote refers to the local files and the local part refers to the website files... maybe it's my misunderstanding, but that seems very strange to me! Anyway, problem fixed.

Comment: Im facing the same issue. Can you post how your config file looks new?

Comment: Sure, but it's on my work machine so it will be tomorrow.

Comment: @beliskna any chance you could post the configuration and describe in more detail what you had to do? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have access to the code base anymore, it was for a previous job.